# Is it appropriate to blockquote Wikipedia to improve our tag wiki?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-wiki

I'm trying to edit a few of the tags, but since I'm new here I wonder if it is appropriate to blockquote Wikipedia on our tags as long as they are referenced correctly?

An example is shown on the **best-practice** tag:

[image]

Comment: If you agree with what is said, then I don't see why not. If you don't agree with what is said, fix it in Wikipedia, and then quote it :)

Comment: LOL! That's the way to do it. Just have to re-initiate my Wikipedia-account then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia and Stack Exchange use the same [CC Attribution ShareAlike](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. As long as we provide a link back, we should be free to copy and adapt Wikipedia's content.

In the long term, we should aim to contextualize descriptions as they relate to our site. See the helpful guidelines in the sidebar when you edit a tag wiki.

> The tag wiki **excerpt** is a brief plain
>   text introduction to the topic that
>   the tag represents. It is shown at the
>   top of tag question lists, and as a
>   tooltip wherever the tag appears.
>   Complete this first!
>
> The **full tag wiki**
>   is a detailed introduction to the
>   topic, suitable as a destination for
>   those curious about it:
>
> - what questions should have this tag?
> - some basic definitions
> - brief introduction to the subject
> - important general links
> - one reasonably sized page

Comment: Thanx! I'll keep this in mind while editing. BR

Comment: @Benny Wow, you're still going! Beware the law of diminishing returns. At this point it might be better to focus on (a) making sure questions have appropriate tags or (b) contextualizing some of the tag wikis as described above. Thanks!

Comment: Thanx for the advice! I'll do my best to contextualize the tags. It's fun and good practice for me where "labeling" were one of the corner stones in my IA-education :)

Comment: we recently switched from cc-by-sa 2.5 to cc-by-sa 3.0, so we are now 100% compatible.